# Same name functions in same class - is there an elegant way to determine which to call?

Tags: python, version-control, python-3.6, python-decorators

I am trying to do product version control in Python scripts for a specific reason, but I couldn't figure out how to do it in an elegant way.

Currently, I am doing something like the below. However, the scripts are hard to maintain when version content is changed.

```
class Product(object):

    def __init__(client):
        self.version = client.version  # Get client version from another module

    def function():
        if self.version == '1.0':
            print('for version 1.0')
        elif self.version == '2.0':
            print('for version 2.0')
        else:
            print(f'function not support {self.version}')
```

Therefore, I want to do something like the below to separate the functions with the same name.

```
class Product(object):

    def __init__(client):
        self.version = client.version  # Get client version from another module

    def function():
        print('for version 1.0')

    def function():
        print('for version 2.0')
```

I was thinking about to use **decorator** to achieve this:

```
class Product(object):

    def __init__(client):
        self.version = client.version  # Get client version from another module

    @version(1.0)
    def function():
        print('for version 1.0')

    @version(2.0)
    def function():
        print('for version 2.0')
```

However, I failed to figure out how... it seems like a decorator cannot do this kind operation or I just don't understand how to.

Is there a elegant way to do this?

Comment: The "standard" way to solve this would be to have  `ProductV1` and `ProductV2` then your `Product` class simply has an `_impl` attribute that is assigned to a `ProductV<version>` and all the methods are forwarded like `def function(self): return self._impl.function()`. In python you could even avoid defining them by using `__getattr__`. Also: `ProductVX` would simply define the basic operations and you can put in `Product` the facade methods that you can build on top of the basic methods.

Comment: I forgot to say: by "standard solution" I mean: this is what you'd do in most programming languages where you cannot use stuff like decorators for example. Also: if you have big classes using decorators makes your class quite big and hard to work with. It's easier to separate completely the version-specific implementations.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Inheritance is probably the best way to do this, but since you asked specifically about decorators, I wanted to show you could do this using decorators.

You'll need to use a dictionary to store your functions by version, and then look up which version to use at runtime. Here's an example.

```
version_store = {}

def version(v):
    def dec(f):
        name = f.__qualname__
        version_store[(name, v)] = f
        def method(self, *args, **kwargs):
            f = version_store[(name, self.version)]
            return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
        return method
    return dec

class Product(object):
    def __init__(self, version):
        self.version = version

    @version("1.0")
    def function(self):
        print("1.0")

    @version("2.0")
    def function(self):
        print("2.0")

Product("1.0").function()
Product("2.0").function()
```

Comment: You probably want `f.__qualname__` to avoid conflict between `Product.function` and `Ambassadorial.function`...

Comment: Python doesn't complain that there are two methods with the same name in a class? Which one does it use? (Yes I realise that the decorator returns the same function anyway, but Python doesn't know)

Comment: @Amadan Instead of using the qualified name, would it be possible to create a separate `version_store` per class?

Comment: @Bergi methods are just members on the class. Each declaration replaces the last version, but it doesn't matter because, like you said, they're all the same :)

Comment: The problem with “one version store per class” is - there’s nowhere to put it. Ideally you’d think it would be best to make a secret attribute on the `Products` and put all of the product-related versioned methods there - but at the time the annotation is resolving, `Product` doesn’t exist yet.

Answer (score 9):

Could you put your `Product` class into two modules, v1 and v2, then import them conditionally?

For example:

`Productv1.py`

```
class Product(object):
    def function():
        print('for version 1.0')
```

`Productv2.py`

```
class Product(object):
    def function():
        print('for version 2.0')
```

Then in your main file:

`main.py`

```
if client.version == '1.0':
    from Productv1 import Product
elif client.version == '2.0':
    from Productv2 import Product
else:
    print(f'function not support {self.version}')

p = Product
p.function()
```

Comment: Actually, I used similar way to do version control before by creating multiple py files (e.g. v1, v2, v3), which is easiest but these files contain too many "duplicated content".. that's why I am trying to combine them into one CLASS. Thank you for your advice!

Comment: @TimmyLin In that case, you could have a base class, say `Product` that holds all the duplicated content, then have a `Productv1` and `Productv2` that inherits it and just holds what is different. That way there's no duplicated code.

Comment: And the MAIN reason is .. too many versions (but with small changes) in this product and it's still growing, so if I do this, the folder/files structure will become ugly eventually :|

Comment: Ah in that case my suggestion cant go any further. Good luck.

Comment: Exactly, the B plan is to use inherit from a main class. But I still want to know if there's any cool and elegant way to do this. If there isn't, I will mark you the best answer! thank you!

Answer (score 7):

As another option, you could go for some factory to create your class.

Create your versioned functions (note the `self` parameter). This can be done in a different module. Also, add some collection to fetch the function based on the version number.

```
def func_10(self):
    print('for version 1.0')

def func_20(self):
    print('for version 2.0')

funcs = {"1.0": func_10,
         "2.0": func_20}
```

Add a base class that contains the static parts of your implementation and a utility class to create your instances in:

```
class Product:
    def __init__(self, version):
        self.version = version

class ProductFactory(type):
    @classmethod
    def get_product_class(mcs, version):
        # this will return an instance right away, due to the (version) in the end
        return type.__new__(mcs, "Product_{}".format(version.replace(".","")), (Product,), {"function": funcs.get(version)})(version)
        # if you want to return a class object to instantiate in your code omit the (version) in the end
```

Using this:

```
p1 = ProductFactory.get_product_class("1.0")
p2 = ProductFactory.get_product_class("2.0")
print(p1.__class__.__name__) # Product_10
p1.function() # for version 1.0
print(p1.function) # <bound method func_10 of <__main__.Product_10 object at 0x0000000002A157F0>>
print(p2.__class__.__name__) # Product_20
p2.function() # for version 2.0 
print(p2.function) # <bound method func_20 of <__main__.Product_20 object at 0x0000000002A15860>>
```

Comment: cool! although it's a little bit complex, it could do the thing. however I am looking for a way that I don't need to separate functions into 2 variables `p1, p2`, but this is absolutely a good answer. Thank you!

Comment: @TimmyLin Actually, the functions are not separated into two variables. `p1` and `p2` are separate instances of subclasses of `Product`, each with their own implementation of `function` based on the `version` (which is supposed to be your `client.version`). Basically, this example builds the class with the implementation of `function` that is required for the given version instead of having one class implementing all possible 'versions' of `function`. However, I think you picked the best answer for your requirement, this was mereley added for completeness sake :)

Comment: BTW: you could replace `ProductFactor` with a `Product` class and define a `__new__` method to do what the `get_product_class` does. In this way the code has less boiler-plate.

Answer (score 6):

**In general, don't.** [Method overloading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading) is discouraged in Python. If you have to differentiate on class level, read [Loocid's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52252054/same-name-functions-in-same-class-is-there-an-elegant-way-to-determine-which-t/52252154#52252154). I won't repeat his excellent post.

If you want in on a method level because the difference is small enough for that, try something like this:

```
class Product:

    def method(self):
        if self.version == "1.0":
            return self._methodv1()
        elif self.version == "2.0":
            return self._methodv2()
        else:
            raise ValueError("No appropriate method for version {}".format(self.version))

    def _methodv1(self):
        # implementation

    def _methodv2(self):
        # implementation
```

Note here:

1. Use of methods starting with an underscore, to indicate those are
   the implementation.
2. Keeping the methods nice and tidy without
   contamination between the versions
3. Raising an error for unexpected versions (crash early and hard).
4. In my not so humble opinion, this will be a lot clearer for other people reading your post than using decorators.

Or:

```
class Product:

    def method_old(self):
        # transform arguments to v2 method:
        return self.method()

    def method(self):
        # implementation
```

1. In case you want to totally deprecate previous usage, and want to drop version 1.0 support in the future.
2. Be sure to give deprecation warnings, so to not surprise users of a library with sudden changes.
3. It is arguably the better solution if nobody else uses your code.

I get the vibe my first method would be more suitable to your problem at hand, but I wanted to include the second for posterity. If you edit your code 10 years from now, that one will make you happier. If you edit code using the current code tomorrow, the first method will make you happier.

Comment: Thank you for the honest advice! Everyone here did help me a lot, it's struggle to say who's solution is the best. Let's say.. the project I am working on is .. extremely huge, we want the version difference can be listed out very CLEARLY and can be maintained easily. That's why I insist to use decorator to do this due to it's the clearest and beauty one.

To be honest, if I am working on another smaller project, I will definitely choose your 2nd options and also @Loocid's one.

Comment: We can only ever look at a small part at the time - in a huge project, only you can pick the right option, due to the style of the rest of the project. Best we can do is list the possibilities. Good luck with it !

Comment: Designing a new framework for development is hard, I really like your first suggestion and I have discussed that with team, maybe there's a chance we will go that way or @BartoszKP's way. Both are excellent.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a Python developer, but I can't help but wonder why you don't just do something like this:

```
class Product(object):
    def __init__(self, version):
        self.version = version
    def function(self):
        print('for version ' + self.version)
```

Comment: Because this is just a example that make ppl easier to understand what I was trying to do. The function is not only printing things but do a lot of operations. Actually I don't even need to self.version to be passed into function method, I just need it to locate which function I want to load while program is running.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can do, `dict.get` to call a function and do `print` in `lambda` if nothing is right:

```
def func_1(self):
        print('for version 1.0')

    def func_2(self):
        print('for version 2.0')
    def function(self):
       funcs = {"1.0": self.func_1,
                "2.0": self.func_2}
       funcs.get(self.version,lambda: print(f'function not support {self.version}'))()
```

Example:

```
class Product(object):

    def __init__(self,version):
        self.version = version

    def func_1(self):
        print('for version 1.0')

    def func_2(self):
        print('for version 2.0')
    def function(self):
       funcs = {"1.0": self.func_1,
                "2.0": self.func_2}
       funcs.get(self.version,lambda: print(f'function not support {self.version}'))()
Product('1.0').function()
Product('2.0').function()
Product('3.0').function()
```

Output:

```
for version 1.0
for version 2.0
function not support 3.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use decorators for this

```
def v_decorate(func):
   def func_wrapper(name):
       return func(name)
   return func_wrapper
```

And

```
@v_decorate
def get_version(name):
   return "for version {0} ".format(name)
```

You can call it

```
get_version(1.0)

   'for version 1.0 '

get_version(2.0)
'for version 2.0 '
```

Comment: I am sorry, I am not sure if I understand this correctly. The `v_decorate` is to add an extra argument `name` to the original function? don't understand how to combine this to my same name functions.. Orz

Comment: Doing this is nothing different from the first example I wrote in description..
passing version to `v_decorate` and put into called function is kinda extra steps. Modify my function to `function(self): print(f'for version {self.version}')` can do the exactly same thing without decorator..

Comment: I don't see what this decorator actually accomplishes ?